# How to add .html to razor pages url?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-8

I'm new to ASP.NET and Razor Pages. I've a web app where I want to show URLs with html extension. So, the `localhost/login.html` should go to `Pages/Login.cshtml`. I've read about `AddRazorPages` and `AddRazorPagesOptions()` but all I can understand that by default Razor Pages routes `localhost/` to `Pages/index.cshtml` and `localhost/product/create` to `Pages/Product/Create.cshtml` and so on. How to intercept this is beyond me and whatever I read is getting way above my head.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
(Program.cs)
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(opt =>
{
    opt.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/*.html", "/*");
});
```

Can anyone help me (with little explanation) how to achieve this? Or point me to resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IPageRouteModelConvention Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.ipageroutemodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Allows customization of the PageRouteModel.

[PageConventionCollection.AddFolderRouteModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection.addfolderroutemodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-8.0) Method creates and adds an IPageRouteModelConvention that invokes an action on PageRouteModel instances for all page under the specified folder.

So if we want to show URLs with html extension, we need to custom
the PageRouteModel , try the below code:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
  {
      o.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", pageRouteModel =>
      {
          foreach (var selectorModel in pageRouteModel.Selectors)
              selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template =  selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template + ".html";
      });
 });
```

result:   the localhost/Privacy.html should go to Pages/Privacy.cshtml:

[image]

**Or** add `@page "/Privacy.html"` in the Pages/Privacy.cshtml ,but this way we need to add it for every cshtml page.